# What is file type of Bulk Data Load Jobs results-file while importing data through Data import Wizard?

Tags: force.com, data-loader, csv, data-import-wizard

New to Salesforce.I imported a certain .csv file into Salesforce through Data Import Wizard, when I clicked on data batch reports, a file named 'reports' was downloaded. But not sure or clue what type of file is it.

Comment: When you say clicked on data batch reports, do you mean that you went to Setup --> Bulk Data Load Jobs and clicked on the Job Id?

Comment: @JayantDas when data is imported, it is done in batches, so when I selected a batch report to download, that file is of which type. The batch was of 10000 entries migrated from a csv